# SQL - Return Null values when a value is provided

Tags: sql, bi-publisher

I am developing a report in BI Publisher that accepts user input as search criteria and the results are rendered into a pdf template. The user input is used as parameters in the SQL query I have to do the search

I am testing with the following data

```
PER_FNAME   PER_MNAME   PER_LNAME
Stuart      Easterly    Adams
Stuart      Ronald      Adams
Stuart      Ronald      Adams
Stuart                  Adams
Stuart                  Adams
```

The results are based on user input and need to conform to the following rules/conditions:

The user will either enter a middle name or leave it blank(null)

1. If middle name is provided (not null) return the middle name where there is a match AND where the middle name is null

   E.g. If user enters 'Ronald' results should be

   ```
   PER_FNAME   PER_MNAME   PER_LNAME
   Stuart      Ronald      Adams
   Stuart      Ronald      Adams
   Stuart                  Adams
   Stuart                  Adams
   ```
2. If middle name is null return all middle names values including null

   E.g. if the user enter nothing in the middle name field the results should be

   ```
   PER_FNAME   PER_MNAME   PER_LNAME
   Stuart      Easterly    Adams
   Stuart      Ronald      Adams
   Stuart      Ronald      Adams
   Stuart                  Adams
   Stuart                  Adams
   ```

So far I have the following sql

```
    SELECT 
      PER_FNAME,
      PER_MNAME,
      PER_LNAME
      FROM
      (SELECT   
        Asset.ASSET_NUM AS BN_REN
        FROM SIEBEL.S_ASSET Asset
        WHERE
        Asset.NAME = 'Business Names'
        AND Asset.status_cd = 'Registered'
      ) Q1

      LEFT JOIN 

     (SELECT 
       Asset.ASSET_NUM AS PER_ASSET,
       Contact.FST_NAME AS PER_FNAME,
       Contact.MID_NAME AS PER_MNAME,
       Contact.LAST_NAME AS PER_LNAME
       FROM siebel.s_asset_con aCon, siebel.s_asset Asset, siebel.s_contact Contact
       WHERE Asset.row_id = aCon.asset_id
       AND aCon.CONTACT_ID = Contact.ROW_ID
     ) Q2

    ON Q1.BN_REN = Q2.PER_ASSET

    WHERE 
      PER_FNAME = NVL(:FIRST_NAME, PER_FNAME)
      AND (PER_MNAME IS NULL OR PER_MNAME = :MID_NAME)
      AND PER_LNAME = NVL(:LAST_NAME, PER_LNAME)
```

If the user inputs a middle name the results are as expected and I get both null and the right values. However when nothing is entered in for middle name I get only null values not all values.

Is there a way to cater to both conditions in the one sql? and if so how do I go about achieving it?

Comment: Use `AND (PER_MNAME IS NULL OR :MID_NAME IS NULL OR PER_MNAME = :MID_NAME)`